# Does Visual Studio Professional support Perl?

Tags: perl, visual-studio-2017, syntax-highlighting

There appears to be no support for Perl projects in Visual Studio 2017 Professional. Is there an extension to bring syntax highlighting and reference detection (known as "Navigate To" in Visual Studio)?

Comment: There are plugins available that provide syntax highlighting and debugger support (try Google) but nothing that offers *jump to definition*. What do you mean by *reference detection*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS 2017 supports Perl syntax highlighting according to this [release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.0):

> Language file types listed by support level:
>
> ```
> Supports only Syntax Colorization and Autocomplete:
>     .., Objective-C, Perl, PowerShell, ...
> Supports Code Snippets (in addition to Syntax Colorization and Autocomplete):
>     ..., Lua, Perl, PHP, ...
> Supports Navigate To (in addition to Syntax Colorization and Autocomplete):
>     ...
> ```

Comment: You might want to [edit] your question and include a citation of the relevant part of the release note.